# Turn Pandas muti-Index into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar dataframe:

```
 action_type            value
    0   0   link_click          1
        1   mobile_app_install  5
        2   video_view          181
        3   omni_view_content   2
    1   0   post_reaction       32
        1   link_click          124
        2   mobile_app_install  190
        3   video_view          6162
        4   omni_custom         2420
        5   omni_activate_app   4525
    2   0   comment             1
        1   link_click          53
        2   post_reaction       23
        3   video_view          2246
        4   mobile_app_install  87
        5   omni_view_content   24
        6   post_engagement     2323
        7   page_engagement     2323
```

I want to transpose so:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can try:

```
(df.set_index('action_type', append=True)
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)['value']
   .unstack('action_type')
)
```

Comment: Ty you are amazing :)